# Redirect loop in CI after installing SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, https

I just installed ssl certificate on my site to change the URL from http:// to https:// Everything is complete and i also added a code in my httpd.conf file to automatically add https :// to the UR So the connection is always secure.

However I am facing a problem when i try to login into the Admin Panel. It Goes in a redirect Loop and the webpage gives me a `"This webpage has a redirect loop"` Error.

https://mysite.com Loads fine but https:/mysite.com/admin goes into a redirect loop.

site is built up using codeigniter Framework for php.
Please Help.

I added this code to my httpd.conf file

```
#
# Redirect http Request to https
# The lines below are used to redirect http request to https
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's easier to understand if you add the httpd.conf code...

Comment: I have added the code... please let me know if you find something

Answer (score 0):

```
Open config file from location application/config/config.php and enable or set hooks to true like this:

$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
Then create a new file named hooks.php inside the config folder (i.e. application/config/hooks.php) and add the following code in it:

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
    'filename' => 'ssl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
Now create a new directory named hooks inside the application folder (i.e. application/hooks) and then create a new file named ssl.php inside the hooks folder (i.e. application/hooks/ssl.php).

Add the following code in the ssl.php file:

function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
        // redirecting to ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } else {
        // redirecting with no ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```